# z3 runtime: Calling constant directly VS passing as parameter

Tags: z3

I have come across some unusual runtime behaviour in z3, and I wanted to ask why it is happening:

Example 1:

```
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.6)

(set-info :status unknown)
(define-sort FPN () (Float32))

(declare-const a1 FPN)
(assert (fp.eq a1 ((_ to_fp 8 24) RNE 1)))
(declare-const a2 FPN)
(assert (fp.eq a2 ((_ to_fp 8 24) RNE -1)))
(declare-const a3 FPN)
(assert (fp.eq a3 ((_ to_fp 8 24) RNE 0.5)))

(define-fun afun ((x FPN) (a1Param FPN) (a2Param FPN) (a3Param FPN)) FPN (fp.mul RNE (fp.add RNE (fp.mul RNE a1Param x) a2Param) a3Param ))

(assert
  (forall ((x0 FPN)) (not (fp.geq (afun x0 a1 a2 a3) x0)))
)

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

Example 2:

```
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.6)

(set-info :status unknown)
(define-sort FPN () (Float32))

(declare-const a1 FPN)
(assert (fp.eq a1 ((_ to_fp 8 24) RNE 1)))
(declare-const a2 FPN)
(assert (fp.eq a2 ((_ to_fp 8 24) RNE -1)))
(declare-const a3 FPN)
(assert (fp.eq a3 ((_ to_fp 8 24) RNE 0.5)))

(define-fun afun ((x FPN)) FPN (fp.mul RNE (fp.add RNE (fp.mul RNE a1 x) a2) a3 ))

(assert
  (forall ((x0 FPN)) (not (fp.geq (afun x0) x0)))
)

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

Example 1 has a runtime of ~0.26s, Example 2 has a runtime of ~0.35s, despite the only difference being that in function afun I am either calling the constants directly or passing them as parameters.
I have additionally noticed that sometimes the opposite happens (calling a constant directly being faster than passing it as a parameter).

I can't figure out why this is happening, so I wanted to ask here.
Thanks so much for any responses!

Comment: Are you sure these measurements are statistically significant? (i.e., if you run each experiment ten-million times and look at the averages, does it persist?) From your description, and the measurements so small as 0.26/0.35s, I don't think it'd be reasonable to reach any conclusion unless you've done extensive measurement that suggests a persisting difference.

Comment: @alias In bigger/more complex problems switching between calling constants directly vs as parameters has caused time differences of several minutes for me, which is why this was significant to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems get rewritten into Boolean logic and `fp.mul` is simply hard to analyze, just like multiplication in many other theories. You're basically at the mercy of the SAT solver, which uses various kinds of heuristics to solve many problems quickly, but on any given problem, it's not easy to predict it's behavior. It's very common for tiny changes to the input to result in huge changes in solving time. You can run Z3 with `-v:10` to see which tactics get applied and to see some of the statistics from the SAT solver.